# Change Xcode IDE color by project

Tags: xcode8

Is there a way to change Xcode IDE color by project or workspace ?

I know we can change it on preferences, Fonts & Colors but it will affect whole environment.

This can be helpful when duplicating a project and you have two windows, with almost same code but different projects.

Comment: Not AFAIK. You can always "suggest" this as a new feature at https://bugreport.apple.com/.

Comment: I will wait till next week, if no solution pops up I will open. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After opening a bug report and addressing this enhancement the Apple answer is:

> Apple Developer Relations May 31 2017, 2:42 PM
>
> Thank you for your feedback, it is noted. Engineering has determined that there are
> currently no plans to address this issue.
>
> We are now closing this bug report.
>
> If you have questions or comments about the resolution, please update
> your bug report with that information so we can respond.